# MYSQL Fulltext search and LIKE

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am working with MySQL full text search but find it lacking in situations where your string is part of a word within a field. If my field is "New York Times" and I search for "Time" I get no results. The hackish way to solve this is to set up two queries, one that does a full text search and the other that does:

```
SELECT * FROM ___ WHERE 'string' LIKE %searchterm%
```

Is there any way that I can set up my full text search to solve this issue so I don't have to run the extra query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've basically given up on MySql's full text search in favor of [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) -- a dedicated full-text search engine which implements MySql's network protocol so you can "interpose" it between your clients and a MySql server, losing nothing and gaining rich, serious full-text capabilities. Maybe it's not suitable for your needs (which you don't fully express), but I think it's at least work checking out!

Comment: Cool thanks a lot.  Just to clarify my question.  

I have a field that is the New York Giants.  If I add that to the fulltext index and then search "giant"  nothing will come up.  How can I use fulltext search to return results in cases like these?  

I'll check out Sphinx. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Russ, you're looking for **stemming** plugins (for mysql 5.1, 5.0 didn't support them), e.g. http://www.mnogosearch.org/doc/msearch-udmstemmer.html .

Comment: Thanks so much Alex, I appreciate the help.  Unfortunatley, my hands are bound and I cannot upgrade to mysql 5.1. But I'm a bit confused, i undersatnd that in 5.0 I can't use customer parsers but does this mean that there is no native mysql method to do stemming in 5.0?

Comment: @Russ, yep, that's what MySql's docs say -- plugins to full text search, e.g. for stemming, were only introduced in 5.1. I recommend Sphinx, anyway;-).

Answer (score 8):

You can use wild cards in your full text search. More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

```
SELECT * FROM _____ WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('time*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: hmmm nice nice.  I didn't think of that. Only issue is that its a poor substitute for stemming since it won't match "timing" and words like that. I opted to do both a fulltext search and a LIKE %...% string matching search.  Its a bit tedious and is extra querying but generates fairly solid results.

Comment: It also doesn't help when a search needs to go the other way.  For example, the data includes the word "ipad" but the user searches for "ipads".  The wildcard will not help in this case.

Comment: @Arnold `LIKE %...%` will kill your performance, because SQL won't use indexes. If you go for that approach, you probably won't need the fulltext search.